# Storing objects to an array or arraylist in php

Tags: php

I'm coming from Java and just continued learning PHP. So, I'm trying to follow some similar patterns in that I use in Java to get values from database.

There's just one problem that I don't know how to solve. I can't find a way to properly **store objects** (which has its values / attributes set using the `set()` methods) **to an** `Array` or `ArrayList`. I think that PHP don't have `ArrayList` or `List` or `HashMaps`

But anyways, I basically want to know the correct idiom,syntax or way to store objects which I instantiated by keyword `new` to the common type of PHP collection where I can easily retrieve objects from later by using `get()` methods.

```
    function getAllAnnouncementByMostRecent()
    {
        try{
            $SQL = "CALL getAllAnnouncementByMostRecent()";
            $spGetAnnouncements = $this->connection->prepare($SQL);
            $spGetAnnouncements->execute();
            $resultSet = $spGetAnnouncements->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $announcementList = [];
            foreach($resultSet as $row){
                $announcement = new Announcement();
                $announcement->setId($row['announcement_id']);
                $announcement->setTitle($row['announcement_title']);
                $announcement->setContent($row['announcement_content']);
                $announcement->setDateAdded($row['date_added']);
                $announcementList[] = $announcement;
            }
            return $announcementList;
        }catch (PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

So I tried to retrieve data from it but got an error stating that there's

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
<div class="bottom-menu-content-container">
    <?php
        $announcementDaoImpl = new AnnouncementDaoImpl($pdo);
        $announcementList = $announcementDaoImpl->getAllAnnouncementByMostRecent();
        foreach($announcementList as $key => $value)
        {
            echo "<label>". $value. "</label>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

I tried to `var_dump()` the contents of `$announcementList` and I get the ff:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(Announcement)#4 (4) { ["id":"Announcement":private]=> int(1) ["title":"Announcement":private]=> string(23) "Test Announcement Title" ["content":"Announcement":private]=> string(25) "Test Announcement Content" ["dateAdded":"Announcement":private]=> string(19) "2018-04-22 16:12:06" } }
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

--- EDIT (SOLVED) ---

Thanks everyone for your suggestions and help. It was solved by simply accessing the `get()` method of the object as suggested by **William Perron** and **ADyson**

```
<div class="bottom-menu-content-container">
    <?php
        $announcementDaoImpl = new AnnouncementDaoImpl($pdo);
        $announcementList = $announcementDaoImpl->getAllAnnouncementByMostRecent();
        foreach($announcementList as $key => $value)
        {
            echo $value->getTitle(); //no need to cast
        }
        ?>
</div>
```

To those who might see this question during search who might also be coming from a different programming language, the only thing that I was confused was the casting of objects.

Thanks.

--- end of edit ----

Comment: What does function `getAllAnnouncementByMostRecent` return?

Comment: You dont retrieve value in this foreach, you retrieve object. So you should write $value->getId() etc. Assuming that you have implemented object Announcement with all getters and setters or magic methods. Or if i remember, theres magic method __toString()

Comment: You can use PDO's `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` to populate the properties of the class.

Comment: @JozefCipa I added the returned value / contents of `$announcementList` from `getAllAnnouncementByMostRecent()` method on my edit.

Comment: which foreach is giving you the warning? I don't see how the loop through announcementList could giving it, since you return an array. But maybe the loop through $resultSet is the problem?

Comment: @Eakethet Thanks, I'm gonna go try it.

Comment: @Dormilich Alright, I'll try. I'm still learning it so I need to read some info. I'll update this question as soon as I've tried all suggested options. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson I get the `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` message from the php contained by `<div>`

Comment: "the php contained by div", as you put it, includes the call to getAllAnnouncementByMostRecent() which includes the foreach I was talking about. The warning should include a specific line number, so you can be sure where the problem occurs.

Comment: TBH if the announcementList is populated the way you claim, then it's hard to see how any of this code could be the cause of the warning.

Comment: @p3ace PHP doesn't have an equivalent to Java's `ArrayList`, instead it has `array`s which really can be whatever the hell you want. The code you provided does store the objects in a numerically indexed array. your problem seems to be more about how to efficiently access specific elements within that array, which depends highly on the specific use case, of which we have no details in the question

Comment: @WilliamPerron Thanks, you're right. My problem is, how I can `get()` the properties of the object `$announcement` once it's returned. For instance, `$announcement->getTitle()` while using `foreach()` inside the `<div>` considering it's numerically indexed.

Comment: @Eakethet: Your explanation is wrong. Yes, iterating through an array of objects will return objects and not scalars. The choice of variable names will not affect the behaviour of foreach, and the type of the element returned will not cause this error. Indeed it is quite valid to use a bare reference to an object in PHP if it has a toString() method.

Comment: OTOH the OP's description of the problem is inherently contradictory - either there is a typo in the original code not reproduced here, the error reported occurred elsewhere in the code / not in the fragment shown or for some other reason the entity examined by var_dump is not the same one passed to foreach

Comment: @symcbean After update yes, my comment was posted before updating question and adding error message.

Comment: @p3ace try echoing `$value->getId()` instead of simply echoing `$value`, or whatever property needs to be printed

Comment: @WilliamPerron I think you have solved my problem!! But coming from Java, I find it weird that I can access the `get()` method of an object array element without casting it. After trying your suggestion, I was able to retrieve the announcement title by `$value->getTitle()`

Comment: " how I can get() the properties of the object $announcement once it's returned" ...you've already had this explained, but let's try again: Inside your `foreach($announcementList as $key => $value)` loop, `$value` will represent the item in your array currently being looped. In your case, this will be an object of type Announcement, since that's what you placed into the array. So you can just use it like one, and use `$value->getId()` (or whatever methods the class provides) to get at the data items for that object. `$key` will be the index of the array (e.g. 0, 1 etc).

Comment: "I find it weird that I can access the get() method of an object array element without casting it". That's simply because PHP is not strongly-typed. It creates a lot of flexibility but also unfortunately can cause a lot of headaches and requires testing to be a lot more careful, since things which would be caught by the compiler in Java or C# (for example) are not considered a compilation problem in PHP, and can manifest themselves as runtime errors instead.

Comment: @WilliamPerron Thank you.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you. I still need to learn a lot about its differences. But thanks.

Comment: @Everyone Thanks I appreciate it. Sorry for the long description and numerous comments.